# Download File - Ironpython

Tags: .net, arrays, ironpython, createinstance

I am trying to design a simple script to download a file... but i'm stuck...

Wht i did until now:

```
    request = WebRequest.Create(page)       
    request.Credentials = NetworkCredential("name", "pw")
    request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get     
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"        
    response = request.GetResponse()
    length = response.ContentLength

    writeStream = System.IO.FileStream(fi, System.IO.FileMode.Create)           
    Bytes = Array.CreateInstance(int,8192)

    bytesread = response.GetResponseStream()                        
    #encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    readStream = System.IO.StreamReader(bytesread)
    count = readStream.Read(Bytes, 0, 8192)         

    while True:                         
        count = readStream.Read(Bytes, 0, 8192)         
        if count == 0:break
        writeStream.Write(Bytes, 0, bytesread)

    response.Close()
    writeStream.Close()
    response = request.GetResponse()
```

"fi" is filename on my disk, "page" an uURl pointing to z file on the web.

The error is in the CreateInstance, asking for Char array instead of int... but, how can i create an array of chars???

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
bytes = Array[Char](range(8192))
```

Comment: thanks, i finally used downloadfile, but will try this at the next chance !